# Jquery Multiselect OptGroup with ASP.Net Listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have the following code that I use in conjunction with Jquery Multiselct (http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic)

Since listbox doesn't carry an attribute called optgroup, I'm unable to group country by region. The examples discussed in other SO questions don't consider pre-loading data using data source like I'm doing here. Any suggestions on how I can handle grouping of options with Listbox?

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="Country" SelectionMode="Multiple" multiple="multiple"
                        DataSourceID="sds_Country" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Region"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_Country" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
                        SelectCommand="Select distinct Country, Region from tbl_Data order by region, country">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```